# IF statement combined with Chart function in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am still new to VBA and so far I've managed to complete my tasks with some online help, but this one is too far away for my knowledge.

Example sheet here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=50923272994978624314

What I want to do is this - if the column A contains any of the last dates of the months (2015-01-31, 2015-02-28, 2015-03-31, 2015-04-30, 2015-05-31, 2015-06-30, 2015-07-31, 2015-08-31, 2015-09-30, 2015-10-31, 2015-11-30, 2015-12-31), select whichever of those dates column has (select cells with those values to be precise), select corresponding cells in B column (for example, if A10 has 2015-04-30 in it, select B10 value as well) and create a chart (simple 2D clustered column) with those selected values (dates on horizontal axis, money amount on vertical axis).

Idea is to have a chart showing total amount of money at the end of each month (since values in B column are cumulative) it is simple to do it by hand - find last day in the month and see the money value in corresponding B column, then repeat for any last day in the month in the sheet and create a chart. But i will be doing this every day so I am trying to automatize it (via macro).

Comment: how about it your month is not finished yet? the current month?

Comment: No need to check for current month specific, the only conditions is that cells with those dates in column A should be selected (and of course, they corresponding cells in column B).

Comment: It will be easier if you turn column A into dates (either reformat if possible, or build a date in VBA). If you use the DAY function, it will return the day of the month, so add 1 to the date and then use this function. If the answer is 1 then you have the last day of the month.  Loop through each cell and check the date, and you can then build up your range to add a chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would absolutely **not** use a macro.  Instead I would make a column of the dates you want to capture.  Then as you update the values into column A your chart will automatically pick them up hence why I think a macro is useless here and formulas are the way to go.

So lets start off by making that column of dates:

```
Date        MTD Revenue  2015
2015-03-09  € 2,855.270  2015-01-31
2015-03-10  € 3,534.550  2015-02-28
2015-03-11  € 3,791.760  2015-03-31
2015-03-12  € 4,024.680  2015-04-30
2015-03-15  € 4,182.020  2015-05-31
2015-03-16  € 4,317.610  2015-06-30
2015-03-17  € 4,439.900  2015-07-31
2015-03-18  € 4,585.070  2015-08-31
2015-03-19  € 4,798.900  2015-09-30
2015-03-20  € 4,903.830  2015-10-31
2015-03-21  € 4,959.710  2015-11-30
2015-03-23  € 5,203.690  2015-12-31
...         ...
```

If you want to have the dates dynamic you can even use a formula to create the "End of month dates" based on the year.  That way all you have to do is update the year in the column header to change all the dates:

```
C
------------------------------------------------------------
2015
=TEXT(DATE(C$1,1,DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(C1,1,1),0))),"yyyy-mm-dd")
=TEXT(DATE(C$1,MONTH(C2)+1,DAY(EOMONTH(C2,1))),"yyyy-mm-dd")
=TEXT(DATE(C$1,MONTH(C3)+1,DAY(EOMONTH(C3,1))),"yyyy-mm-dd")
=TEXT(DATE(C$1,MONTH(C4)+1,DAY(EOMONTH(C4,1))),"yyyy-mm-dd")
=TEXT(DATE(C$1,MONTH(C5)+1,DAY(EOMONTH(C5,1))),"yyyy-mm-dd")
=TEXT(DATE(C$1,MONTH(C6)+1,DAY(EOMONTH(C6,1))),"yyyy-mm-dd")
=TEXT(DATE(C$1,MONTH(C7)+1,DAY(EOMONTH(C7,1))),"yyyy-mm-dd")
=TEXT(DATE(C$1,MONTH(C8)+1,DAY(EOMONTH(C8,1))),"yyyy-mm-dd")
=TEXT(DATE(C$1,MONTH(C9)+1,DAY(EOMONTH(C9,1))),"yyyy-mm-dd")
=TEXT(DATE(C$1,MONTH(C10)+1,DAY(EOMONTH(C10,1))),"yyyy-mm-dd")
=TEXT(DATE(C$1,MONTH(C11)+1,DAY(EOMONTH(C11,1))),"yyyy-mm-dd")
=TEXT(DATE(C$1,MONTH(C12)+1,DAY(EOMONTH(C12,1))),"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

(Note: I wrapped the dates in the `TEXT(..., "yyyy-mm-dd")` because that is what your column A values were.  Remove that if they are actually dates and not text)

Now we can add an index-match formula to get the corresponding values:

```
A           B           C           D
----------------------------------------------------------------
Date        MTD Revenue  2015        MTD Revenue
2015-03-09  € 2,855.270  2015-01-31  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0))
2015-03-10  € 3,534.550  2015-02-28  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C3,A:A,0))
2015-03-11  € 3,791.760  2015-03-31  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C4,A:A,0))
2015-03-12  € 4,024.680  2015-04-30  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C5,A:A,0))
2015-03-15  € 4,182.020  2015-05-31  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C6,A:A,0))
2015-03-16  € 4,317.610  2015-06-30  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C7,A:A,0))
2015-03-17  € 4,439.900  2015-07-31  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C8,A:A,0))
2015-03-18  € 4,585.070  2015-08-31  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C9,A:A,0))
2015-03-19  € 4,798.900  2015-09-30  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C10,A:A,0))
2015-03-20  € 4,903.830  2015-10-31  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C11,A:A,0))
2015-03-21  € 4,959.710  2015-11-30  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C12,A:A,0))
2015-03-23  € 5,203.690  2015-12-31  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C13,A:A,0))
...         ...
```

It should look like this afterwards:

```
A           B            C           D
------------------------------------------------
Date        MTD Revenue  2015        MTD Revenue
2015-03-09  € 2,855.270  2015-01-31  #N/A
2015-03-10  € 3,534.550  2015-02-28  #N/A
2015-03-11  € 3,791.760  2015-03-31  6,541.27
2015-03-12  € 4,024.680  2015-04-30  6,327.07
2015-03-15  € 4,182.020  2015-05-31  #N/A
2015-03-16  € 4,317.610  2015-06-30  #N/A
2015-03-17  € 4,439.900  2015-07-31  #N/A
2015-03-18  € 4,585.070  2015-08-31  #N/A
2015-03-19  € 4,798.900  2015-09-30  #N/A
2015-03-20  € 4,903.830  2015-10-31  #N/A
2015-03-21  € 4,959.710  2015-11-30  #N/A
2015-03-23  € 5,203.690  2015-12-31  #N/A
...         ...
```

Then we can go ahead and make the chart (2D Clustered column... as requested):

[image]

Final note: Technically since your data is dates, it would be more correct to use a line graph over a 2D Clustered column.

Comment: Don't get carried away with your discussion of line vs column charts. The columns emphasize the values, the line emphasizes the trends.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a vba solution try this:

```
Sub Month_Chart()

Dim mydate As Date
Dim myRange, totrange As Range
   Set totrange = Range("A1:B1")
   'Select Dates based on selection
   For Each c In Selection
   'Build date
   mydate = DateSerial(Left(c, 4), Mid(c, 6, 2), Mid(c, 9, 2))
   'Check last day of month
   If Day(mydate + 1) = 1 Then
        'Create Range
        Set myRange = Range(c, c.Offset(0, 1))
       Set totrange = Union(totrange, myRange)
   End If

   Next c
  'Create Chart
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=totrange
End Sub
```